# JavaScript Why does an inner setTimeout of a Promise runs after an outside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

When run the below code snippet, it outputs `2,1`. Since Promise is a micro-task and everything inside a promise should run before a macro-task (setTimeout), I expect that the output will be `1,2`. So even if there is a macro-task inside a micro-task, I thought the output will be `1,2`.

But it outputs `2,1`.

What's the catch here? Why does it outputs `2,1` instead `1,2`?

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    setTimeout(() =>{
    console.log("1")
 }, 0)
})

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("2")
}, 0)
```

Comment: Whether the inside of your promise is a micro task or not doesn't matter, your second timeout __will__ get set before the first one, hence executes before the first one.

Comment: `But promise executes before the last setTimeout` You're mixing up things here, I guess. The _callback_ will get executed after the promise. The bottom call to `setTimeout` happens before the promise.

Comment: @GLHF "the Q" ... which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise is a micro task and will get executed before `timeout1`, but `timeout1` is already scheduled as a macro task.

When the promise resolves, `timeout2` will get scheduled, but the macrotask Q already has `timeout1` and as such this is already scheduled and will get executed first.

Comment: nevermind ... I need reading glasses :p

Comment: The problem is, JS starts the read the code from above, it sees promise, it schedules it to the Q as first to be executed, then it sees timeout 1(the one with console.log(1)) then it schedules it to the Q, then it continues and sees last timeout, and schedules it to the Q. With this order, I expect the output 1,2. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are correct until the part with it sees timeout 1 and schedules it. It does schedule the promise to execute, it doesn't schedule the timeout1 yet. It finished the current execution, this means that it will schedule timeout2 and then it will execute the promise and schedule timeout1. But timeout2 is already scheduled.

Comment: Ah I see, so when it schedules the promise, then it doesn't schedule what insides it, it continue to schedules other tasks, then execution part comes in, it executes the promise, then it sees timeout1, and schedules it, but meanwhile timeout2 is already scheduled.

Comment: Exactly. It couldn't run the code inside the then because that could generate side effects and a Promise must never execute in a sync manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Eventloop (best Explenation I have ever seen): https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=487

```js
console.log("1")
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log("4")
    setTimeout(() =>{
        console.log("7")
 }, 0)
    console.log("5")
})
console.log("2")
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("6")
}, 0)
console.log("3")
```

The snipped might help you understand it

Promis.resolve().then() does the same as setTimout(0)
so you basically write a timeout inside a timout and thus the eventloop has to loop over it twice

Comment: "best Explenation I have ever seen" best? it's very good, I think I saw a better one though :p

Comment: Actually? I am curious which one

Comment: tongue-in-cheek - I've seen that particular video, and watched it often, I think I saw another video by the same guy to be honest ... the info is the same :p

Answer (score 0):

```js
Promise.resolve().then(/* 1. */() => {
    setTimeout(/* 4. */() => {
        console.log("1") /* 8. */
     }, 0)
    /* 5. */
})


setTimeout(/* 2. */() => {
    console.log("2") /* 6. */
    /* 7. */
}, 0)
/* 3. */
```

1. The following task is added to the microtask queue. Let's call it "micro1":

   ```
   () => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log("1")
       }, 0)
   }
   ```

   The task queues look like

   - Micro: [ micro1 ]
   - Macro: []
2. The following macrotask is scheduled. Let's call it "macro1"

   ```
   () => {
       console.log("2")
   }
   ```

   The task queues look like:

   - Micro: [ micro1 ]
   - Macro: [ macro1 ]
3. The code finishes executing. The event loop picks the next task. The Microtask queue has a priority, the next task to execute is micro1.
4. The following macrotask is scheduled. Let's call it "macro2"

   ```
   () => {
       console.log("1")
   }
   ```

   The timeout is zero, therefore there is nothing to wait. The queue is first in, first out, therefore the task macro2 is added *to the end*. There is no higher priority just because it came from a microtask or anything like that.

   The task queues look like:

   - Micro: []
   - Macro: [ macro1, macro2 ]
5. Task finishes executing. The event loop picks the next task. The Microtask queue is empty, therefore it picks a task from the macrotask queue. Next task to execute is macro1.
6. The task prints `"2"` to the console.
7. Task finishes executing. The event loop picks the next task. The Microtask queue is empty, therefore it picks a task from the macrotask queue. Next task to execute is macro2.
8. The task prints `"1"` to the console.